# Reinitialize jQuery plugin after AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, plugins, navigation

I'm using Infinite AJAX Scroll: https://github.com/webcreate/Infinite-Ajax-Scroll

The user as the possibility to sort results by name for example or to filter results. But, when I do it I have to update navigation links.

The plugin is launched with (for example):

```
jQuery.ias({
  container     : ".listing",
  item      : ".post",
  pagination    : "#content .navigation",
  next      : ".next-posts a",
  loader    : "images/loader.gif"
});
```

How to reinitialize the plugin after an AJAX call to get the new navigation links to work with this plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to call it again, when the ajax call is done:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "yoururl."
}).done(function() { 
  jQuery.ias({
        container     : ".listing",
        item      : ".post",
        pagination    : "#content .navigation",
        next      : ".next-posts a",
        loader    : "images/loader.gif"
  });
});
```

Comment: Actually, this is not working... Navigation is hidden as expected but nothing happens after it...

Comment: I finally switched to an other plugin and it works. Nevertheless, if someone has the solution, it could be interesting.

Comment: just fyi the jquery live method is deprecated.